# Оператор as в C#

Tags: c#

Объясните пожалуйста оператор as в c#. Учил C++ и с него перешёл на C# для изучения Unity. Насколько я понимаю, то оператор as можно понимать как явное приведение типов.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Оператор `as` возвращает значение типа второго операнда, если преобразование типов возможно, или `null`, если невозможно. Этим он отличается от каста `(MyClass)obj`, который выбрасывает исключение, когда преобразование типов невозможно.

Answer (score 2):

Например,

```
var m = someObj as MyClass;
```

Идентично:

```
MyClass m;
try 
{
    m = (MyClass)someObj;
}
catch (InvalidCastException ex)
{
    m = null;
}
```

или же:

```
MyClass m;
if(someObj is MyClass)
{
    m = (MyClass)someObj;
}
else
{
    m = null;
}
```

Возможно, есть какие-то внутренние различия реализации, и, скорее всего, она ближе ко второму варианту, но суть думаю можно понять.